# Getting client application data to enterprise database server

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking to use sql server compact edition for an application where users will not always be connected to the internet.  Once the users regain an internet connection, I want them to be able to send the data to the enterprise sql server.

I started thinking about this and I don't want to have to loop through a recordset to submit each record one-by-one.

Normally, I would just do something like the following:

```
insert into table2
select * from table1
```

Can someone tell me how to proceed or easily send the data from the compact edition to the enterprise edition?

Comment: If you post (T-SQL) code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

The Sync Framework is designed to cover exactly these scenarios of mobile users connecting sporadically from smart devices, laptops and alike. See [Introduction to Sync Framework Database Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx) for a high level discussion. See [Synchronizing Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002.aspx) for a much more detailed discussion. Finally, see [Database Sync - SQL Server and SQL Compact 2-Tier](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=sync&ReleaseId=3422) and 
[Database Sync - SQL Server and SQL Compact N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=sync&ReleaseId=3423) for working code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Try merge replication.  The synchronization function is built in to the SQL Server and CE functions.  You don't have to write code manually to sync rows.